# Which date is further then the selected date

Tags: php, date

How can i check wich date is the further then the other. For my Google Charts i need the date thats the longest away from the other dates because i got two lines in my chart. So if the first date range is shorter then the other one i need to get the date that has the longest range.

This is what i tried but doenst seem to work..

```
$date1 = '01-01-2013';
$date2 = '11-11-2014';

if(date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date1)) < date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date2))){
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date1));
}else{
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date2));
}
```

Comment: Psst, `strtotime` returns an integer.  Comparing integers is going to be easier than comparing hyphen-separated date *strings*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and code are slightly different, you're asking which is the highest but comparing which is the least!

Anyway here's how I would echo the highest:

```
<?php

    $date1 = '01-01-2013';
    $date2 = '11-11-2014';

    echo (strtotime($date1) >= strtotime($date2)) ? $date1 : $date2;
```

Or if you needed to capture the highest:

```
<?php

    $date1 = '01-01-2013';
    $date2 = '11-11-2014';

    $highest_date = (strtotime($date1) >= strtotime($date2)) ? $date1 : $date2;
```

Comment: Aha, well this fixed the problem. I still need what $date1:$date2 does. But ill find that on the web! Thanks for explaining/helping me.

Comment: @Kenny It's called a ternary operator, [info here](http://php.net/ternary) (just above the user comments), basically a shorthand for if statements

Answer (score 1):

```
$date1 = '01-01-2013';
$date2 = '11-11-2014';

if( strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2) ) {
 echo "yes";
} else {
 echo "no";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
$date1 = '01-01-2013';
$date2 = '11-11-2014';
if(strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2)){
echo $date1;
}else{
echo $date2;
}
```